# Android:Unable display image from android storage in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

i m trying to take image file to android storage but android event log show me error  java.lang.RuntimeException and java.lang.nullpointerexception  .

### main java class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridView gridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    custom adCustom= new custom(this);
    gridView.setAdapter(adCustom);

}
```

### custom.java

class custom extends BaseAdapter{

```
Context context;

public custom(Context context){
    this.context=context;

}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return getImage().length;

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ImageView imageView = null;
    if(convertView==null){ imageView=new ImageView(context);}else{imageView=(ImageView)convertView;}

    imageView.setImageURI(getImage()[position]);
    return imageView;
}

Uri[] uri;
String[] mfile=null;
public Uri[] getImage(){
    File file= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    final File[] filelist=file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            return ((filename.endsWith(".jpg"))||(filename.endsWith(".png")));

        }
    }) ;  mfile=new String[filelist.length];
    for(int i=0;i<filelist.length;i++){
        mfile[i]=filelist[i].getAbsolutePath();
    }
    uri=new Uri[mfile.length];
    for(int i=0;i<uri.length;i++){
        uri[i]=Uri.parse(mfile[i]);
    }return uri;}}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You are re-creating and rebuilding the uri array every time getView is called. This is inefficient and can cause concurrency problems. So call getImage() only once, in the constructor of your adapter:

```
public custom(Context context){
    this.context=context;
    getImage();
}
```

Then you can access the images in your getView implementation:

```
imageView.setImageURI(uri[position]);
```

P.S. Name your adapter class something other than `custom`. How about `CustomImageAdapter` ?

Comment: class custom extends BaseAdapter           
{
    Context context;
    public custom(Context context)

    {
        this.context=context;
        getImage();

    }   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ImageView imageView ;
        if(convertView==null){
  imageView=new ImageView(context);

        }else{imageView=(ImageView)convertView;

        }
        imageView.setImageURI(uri[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

Comment: Uri[] uri;
    String[] mfile=null;
    public Uri[] getImage(){
        File file= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        final File[] filelist=file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                return ((filename.endsWith(".jpg"))||(filename.endsWith(".png")));

            }
        }) ;

Comment: mfile=new String[filelist.length];
        for(int i=0;i<filelist.length;i++){
            mfile[i]=filelist[i].getAbsolutePath();
        }
        uri=new Uri[mfile.length];
        for(int i=0;i<uri.length;i++){
            uri[i]=Uri.parse(mfile[i]);
        }
return uri;
    }
}                                   :-  actually program is too long so post a segment

Comment: Uhhh probably should post it in your question. Edit update your question